# Super-Simple Grouping In SQL

Tags: sql, select, group-by, sum

This is probably dumb, but I can't seem to figure this out.

I've written this code:

```
SELECT CoID,
       Job,
       Sum(ActualCost) AS TotalCost
FROM   Database
WHERE  Job = RandomJob
GROUP BY CoID, Job, ActualCost
HAVING ActualCost <> 0
```

And so it spits out this:

```
CoID  Job        TotalCost
X     RandomJob  1
X     RandomJob  1
X     RandomJob  2
X     RandomJob  3
X     RandomJob  5
X     RandomJob  8
```

What I'm trying to get to is this:

```
CoID  Job        TotalCost
X     RandomJob  20
```

Laughing at me is totally fine, since this is probably stupid easy, but please help me figure this out.

Comment: Just do this: `GROUP BY CoID, Job` and `HAVING SUM(ActualCost) <> 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove column `ActualCost` from the `group by` clause, since you want to `sum()` the values in this column over group of rows having the same `CoID` and `Job`.

If you are looking to filter the groups of rows on their total cost, you can use a `having` clause.

```
SELECT CoID,
       Job,
       Sum(ActualCost) AS TotalCost
FROM   Database
WHERE  Job = 'RandomJob'
GROUP BY CoID, Job
HAVING Sum(ActualCost) <> 0
```

Note that since you are filtering on `Job` already, you would as well remove this column from the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` clauses (this value is fixed).

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it!